# Adding WSO2 IS Oauth / OpenId Connect Service Provider using configuration files

Tags: wso2, identityserver4, openid-connect, wso2-identity-server

We are using an automation process currently in our environment. We have WSO2 5.3.0. I need to configure Oauth2/Openid Service Provider using XML configuration files. All the documentation, examples, etc, is oriented to SAML2 and not to Oauth2/OpenId. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you cannot create OAuth / OIDC applications through config files.

You can add the service provider configs through config files. Problem is it does not populate the section "Inbound Authentication Configuration" of OAuth / OIDC application.

Comment: Thank you very most for your useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

See that what user you are logging with has roles to change service providers

see in users and roles , users list and see if it has assinged all roles to edit configuration