# WSO2 IS import OAuth service provider via code

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am attempting to import a service provider into my WSO2 Identity Server by using code.  [This tutorial](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Configuring+a+SP+and+IdP+Using+Configuration+Files) seems to be saying that I to add my service provider xml configuration file to the `WSO2_HOME/repository/identity/service-providers` folder.  However, it's a bit difficult to understand so I'm afraid I'm doing something wrong.

My requirements are:

1. Set up **OAuth** service provider through code
2. Include clientID, clientSecret, grant types, etc. in the .xml config files

My observations are as follows:

1. If I put my service provider .xml file into the `WSO2_HOME/repository/identity/service-providers` folder **before I have ever started my WSO2 server**, the XML file is read and I can authenticate against it.
2. If I put my service provider .xml file into the `WSO2_HOME/repository/identity/service-providers` folder **on a subsequent WSO2 server startup** the file is not read from the `service-providers` folder.
3. I see the tutorial mention the file `sso-idp-config.xml` but I'm not sure where that comes into play.  Do I need to utilize that file somehow?

I am confirming that service providers in observation 2 aren't being loaded into the server by both looking at the data in the H2 database (a row isn't written for the service provider in the `SP_APP` table) and attempting to authenticate against the service provider using a REST call

The tutorial I linked seems pretty comprehensive but it give directions for SAML authentication.  Is there a resource/instructions I can use to do a code-first **OAuth** approach?

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/50809250/6671627

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From IS 5.7.0 supports import and export complete service provider configuration as the xml file. Here is the corresponding [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Importing+or+Exporting+a+Service+Provider). So I think you can use the respective admin service(ApplicationManagementService) to import the OAuth application from your code.

You can refer this [doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Calling+Admin+Services) to get the call the admin service.